# Game development for 2.8

Tags: game-engine, versions, compatibility

At which point are my current 2.78 files compatible with the upcoming 2.8 version? The models will be ok, but what bout the materials? Should I even bother setting them up if I plan on using the new Blender-Game PBR engine?

What about the logic brick? I read that the whole system of game logic will be rearranged and implement new more powerful physics.

So What aspect of my files should I be working on now and which should I leave aside until 2.8 comes out?

Thanks

Comment: This is a good question... even if it's going to be irrelevant soon ;-) I hope we get an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty much unknown at this point, development hasn't really started on 2.8 version

They are not even finished with the design phase yet, so we don't even know how things are going to be, let alone if they will be compatible or if there will be any sort of "automatic conversion" compatibility layer.

Blender always strives to be as much backwards compatible as possible, though so your files are always guarantied to open, even if parts of it will be outdated or useless.

If any of the proposed changes are actually developed I am guessing cycles materials will mostly be compatible with the current version, mesh modeling and modifiers will probably be mostly compatible too, or at least modifiers will be converted to the hypothetical new "node system".
I am guessing any Blender internal or game engine materials, will be incompatible and need refactoring, probably the same with any game engine logic bricks.

This is at this point pretty much my opinion, based on a more-or-less-educated guess. I read development mailing lists discussions and commits daily, but I am no developer nor do I have any saying in the mater.

Anyway Blender 2.8 is at this point very blurry, undefined, and far away in time, it will probably be another year or more before we even see any working nightlies or alpha builds. If you want to do something you probably better use whatever available tools you have right now and worry about conversion later if you still need it then. In all likelihood you will be done with your project anyway by the time Blender 2.8 is out.

Comment: Are you sure? About release date, in 2015 Blender Conference, Ton Roosendal said that it's in progress, and it should take no more than 2 years, that was more than a year ago!

Comment: It's just a guess, at this point I don't think even the developers have any approximate dates. I follow the development very closely and haven't seen any real progress towards 2.8 yet. Only recently (past few weeks) have they even created the new branch where most development will happen, and even after that most developers seem to still be focused on releasing 2.78 before, so I'd say one year is least unlikely minimum. I'd say far more, but that is just my relatively informed opinion, I am in no way a developer nor associated with development tasks.

Answer (score 4):

You can see a [development spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjuEd3Dw7chJ9OyViyJn3MWQPcc6-zQM4yGFxuVFEfo/edit#gid=0) what will change in 2.8 version. You can follow this to adjust on what to work on.

As you can see the only thing agreed on right now is removing the old particle system. This will more than likely break compatibility.

Other things might take a long time till decided and implemented. I would not count on them, it might be years when fully implemented and de-bugged.

**What is actually wrong is your approach to development.**

If you like PBR pipeline and other things that Blender can't offer yet, don't use Blender but use tools that are suitable and work **now**. Do not think you can somehow foretold future and adjust, because blender development is not a thing you can control (if you are not a Blender dev).

Develop your project using tools that are available and **proven** now. Leave the future features for your future project and always test your tools beforehand if they will work in the pipeline.

I understand that you would like to incorporate the things Blender **promises** to add, but such development approach is a road to hell.

To sum up: changing tools, software or just program versions might break your project regardless how well you planned for it. Developing with this in mind is reckless, a strategy should be to minimize non-controllable things.

Comment: that's both interesting answers thanks for your time